# Injecting dependencies into MVC3 WCF services using Ninject extensions

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject-extensions

I have an MVC3 application which should expose some functions via WCF. Some of these functions have dependencies and I'd like to inject them using Ninject, but I must be missing something obvious here as this does not work. Could anyone give a hint? Here's what I did:

1) in my MVC3 app, I add **Ninject Wcf extensions** via nuget.

2) I add a **.svc file** like:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Service="MyWeb.LookupService" 
  Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory"%>
```

3) I **add the corresponding code** like (that's just a test so I'm using a dummy interface right here):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ILookupService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int GetProjectIdByCode(string sCode);
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class LookupService : ILookupService
{
  private readonly ISomeRepository _repository;
  public LookupService(ISomeRepository repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
  }

  public int GetProjectIdByCode(string sCode)
  {
    //... use _repository
  }
}
```

4) in App_Start/**NinjectMVC3.cs**:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    string sConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SomeEntities"].ConnectionString;
    // WCF
    kernel.Bind<ServiceHost>().To<NinjectServiceHost>();

    kernel.Bind<ISomeRepository>()
        .To<AConcreteRepository>()
        .WithConstructorArgument("sConnection", sConnection);
}
```

Now, when I access the svc I get the following exception from Ninject:

> System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Cannot be null Parameter name: root   Source=Ninject
>   ParamName=root   StackTrace:
>          at Ninject.Infrastructure.Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String name) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Ensure.cs:line
>   20
>          at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.GetResolutionIterator(IResolutionRoot
>   root, Type service, Func`2 constraint, IEnumerable`1 parameters,
>   Boolean isOptional, Boolean isUnique) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line
>   258
>          at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line
>   37
>          at Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) in
>   c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject.extensions.wcf\src\Ninject.Extensions.Wcf\NinjectServiceHostFactory.cs:line
>   48
>          at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Ninject, and not Castle Windsor? Not that its a bad choice or something, but there are a pretty good tutorials for wiring Windsor into MVC3

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Ninject because it is the choice of the team, essentially because it can be used in wpf, silverlight and wp7 projects. I could suggest other frameworks only if they comply with at least these specs (and at any rate I should somehow prove that it would be better than NJ for our purposes... I have never used it, but I'm open to suggestions:).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add a protected parameterless constructor to your implementation class.

Guess the servicehost needs a parameterless constructor as well.

I had a look at the Ninject service host factory and from the stack trace provided by you. It looks its failing whne making the following checks:

```
      Ensure.ArgumentNotNull((object) root, "root");
      Ensure.ArgumentNotNull((object) service, "service");
      Ensure.ArgumentNotNull((object) parameters, "parameters");
```

Make sure that you are passing all the required parameters when using the NinjectServiceHostFactory. Worth trying to change the order of registration.

Also go through the following link **[here](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/08/16/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service.aspx)** that explains how to use Ninject to host a wcf service.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood what you meant, but my implementation class already has a public default parameterless ctor using a default connection string. The "production" one will be used through the other constructor with the string parameter, though, so I need my DI to pass it this string. Anyway, I keep getting this error even with both the ctor's.

Comment: I thought that the NInject would use a parameterless constructor on the server to load. Can you have a look into the NInjectServiceHostFactory on how it hosts a WCF Service. For sure its something to do with NInject. You can use dotpeek to see the implemenation of NInjectServiceHostFactory.

Comment: I looked into the code in Ninject and seems like its failing because some parameter is failing to be passed.